# Can a drop-down menu list item be launched without clicking on the text if the cell is wider?

Tags: css

drop down items must be clicked directly on the item text, even if the cell is wider. Can I make it so that you can click anywhere on the block that the item is in to launch it?

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to put up what you have tried so far to achieve what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you use div you can click to div and go anywhere...

```
<a href="google.com"><div>Hello</div></a>
```